# Regex remove everything after Regex Match

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $str);
```

I have this code, this removes all encoded chars, how can I make it remove everything after the first match (including the first match)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a wildcard in the regexp:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF].*/', '', $str);
```

Comment: `s` flag might be necessary here.